# На некоторых серверах не отрабатывает [L] в .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Есть у меня такой .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  ^api/(.+)  /site/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/angular%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) /site/angular/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/static/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/angular/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/vendor/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/controllers/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/css/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/js/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/directives/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/img/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/modules/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/services/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/style/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/views/
RewriteRule .*? site/angular/index.php
```

Сайт на *angularj +api+php* страницы.

api — читает папку `/site/api/` — здесь проект api. Вся статика в папке `/site/angular/`. Остальные запросы входят в `site/angular/index.php`

Но есть еще и админка и куча директорий, к которым надо дать доступ напрямую.

Проблема в том, что не работает ключ `[L]` после

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/site/angular%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+) /site/angular/$1 [L]
```

, то есть если запрашиваю файл  `/directives/directive_name.js` то все равно запрос попадает в `site/angular/index.php`

Что здесь не так? на одном сервере это работает, на локальном работает, но при переносе на другой сервер ключ `[L]` не работает.

Comment: файл то запрашиваемый точно перенесли? и напишите на каком сервере работает а на каком нет. если где-то работает а где-то нет, то дело в сервере и его настройках,а не .htaccess.

Comment: Точно перенес все, как было. возможно это и проблема сервера, но как сервер может повлиять на ключ [L]? Остальные правила .htaccess все работают.